# upgrading gulp from 3 to 4 - Task function must be specified error - what to do?

Tags: gulp

I had a simple javascript webpage and used gulp 3. Now (as I understand) node 10 crashes with gulp 3 so that ive upgraded to gulp 4. I have a very limited knowledge about gulp and read tutorials now on how to upgrade and I am still getting error:  Task function must be specified.

Any help would be great. thanks!!

```
    var gulp = require('gulp');
    var sass = require('gulp-sass');
    var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
    var cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
    var rename = require("gulp-rename");
    var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
    var cache = require('gulp-cache');
    var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');

    // Compiles SCSS files from /scss into /css
    gulp.task('sass', function (done) {
        gulp.src('app/scss/styles.scss')
            .pipe(sass())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
            .pipe(browserSync.reload({
                stream: true
            }))
        done()
    });

    // Minify compiled CSS
    gulp.task('minify-css', ['sass'], function (done) {
         gulp.src('app/css/styles.css')
            .pipe(cleanCSS({
                compatibility: 'ie8'
            }))
            .pipe(rename({
                suffix: '.min'
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
            .pipe(browserSync.reload({
                stream: true
            }))
        done()
    });

    // Minify custom JS
    gulp.task('minify-js', function (done) {
        gulp.src('app/js/index.js')
            .pipe(uglify())
            .pipe(rename({
                suffix: '.min'
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('js'))
            .pipe(browserSync.reload({
                stream: true
            }))
        done()
    });

    // Copy vendor files from /node_modules into /vendor

    gulp.task('copy', function (done) {
        gulp.src([
            'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/**/*',
            '!**/npm.js',
            '!**/bootstrap-theme.*',
            '!**/*.map'
        ])
            .pipe(gulp.dest('vendor/bootstrap'))

        gulp.src(['node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js', 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'])
            .pipe(gulp.dest('vendor/jquery'))

        gulp.src(['node_modules/jquery-easing/*.js'])
            .pipe(gulp.dest('vendor/jquery-easing'))

        /*gulp.src(['node_modules/waypoints/lib/jquery.waypoints.js'])
            .pipe(gulp.dest('vendor/waypoint'))*/
        gulp.src(['node_modules/animate.css/animate.css'])
            .pipe(gulp.dest('vendor/animate'))
        /*    gulp.src(['node_modules/scrollreveal/dist/scrollreveal.js'])
                .pipe(gulp.dest('vendor/scrollreveal'))*/
        done()
    })

    // Optimizing Images
    gulp.task('images', function(done) {
        gulp.src('app/images/**/*.+(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)')
        // Caching images that ran through imagemin
            .pipe(cache(imagemin({
                interlaced: true,
            })))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'));
        done()
    });


    // Default task
    /*gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'minify-css', 'minify-js', 'copy']);*/
    gulp.task('default', gulp.series('sass', 'minify-css', 'minify-js', 'copy'));

    // Configure the browserSync task
    gulp.task('browserSync', function (done) {
        browserSync.init({
            server: {
                baseDir: ''
            },
            port: process.env.PORT || 8080
        });
        done()
    })

    // Dev task with browserSync
    //old:
   /*
    gulp.task('dev', ['browserSync', 'sass', 'minify-css', 'minify-js', 'images'], function () {
        gulp.watch('scss/!*.scss', ['sass']);
        gulp.watch('css/!*.css', ['minify-css']);
        gulp.watch('js/!*.js', ['minify-js']);
        // Reloads the browser whenever HTML or JS files change
        gulp.watch('*.html', browserSync.reload);
        gulp.watch('js/!**!/!*.js', browserSync.reload);
    });*/

   //new
    gulp.task('watch', function(){
        gulp.watch('app/scss/*.scss')
            .on('change', function(path, stats) {
                console.log('File ' + path + ' was changed');
            }).on('unlink', function(path) {
            console.log('File ' + path + ' was removed');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When converting to gulp 4, all Task arrays:

`gulp.task('minify-css', ['sass'], function (done) {`

should be using series:

`gulp.task('minify-css', gulp.series('sass', function (done) {`

final file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
var rename = require("gulp-rename");
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var cache = require('gulp-cache');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');

// Compiles SCSS files from /scss into /css
gulp.task('sass', function (done) {
    gulp.src('app/scss/styles.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream: true
        }))
    done()
});

// Minify compiled CSS
gulp.task('minify-css', gulp.series('sass', function (done) {
    gulp.src('app/css/styles.css')
        .pipe(cleanCSS({
            compatibility: 'ie8'
        }))
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: '.min'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream: true
        }))
    done()
}));

// Minify custom JS
gulp.task('minify-js', function (done) {
    gulp.src('app/js/index.js')
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: '.min'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('js'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream: true
        }))
    done()
});

// Copy vendor files from /node_modules into /vendor

gulp.task('copy', function (done) {
    gulp.src([
        'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/**/*',
        '!**/npm.js',
        '!**/bootstrap-theme.*',
        '!**/*.map'
    ])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('vendor/bootstrap'))

    gulp.src(['node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js', 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('vendor/jquery'))

    gulp.src(['node_modules/jquery-easing/*.js'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('vendor/jquery-easing'))

    /*gulp.src(['node_modules/waypoints/lib/jquery.waypoints.js'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('vendor/waypoint'))*/
    gulp.src(['node_modules/animate.css/animate.css'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('vendor/animate'))
    /*    gulp.src(['node_modules/scrollreveal/dist/scrollreveal.js'])
            .pipe(gulp.dest('vendor/scrollreveal'))*/
    done()
})

// Optimizing Images
gulp.task('images', function(done) {
    gulp.src('app/images/**/*.+(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)')
    // Caching images that ran through imagemin
        .pipe(cache(imagemin({
            interlaced: true,
        })))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'));
    done()
});


// Default task
/*gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'minify-css', 'minify-js', 'copy']);*/
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('sass', 'minify-css', 'minify-js', 'copy'));

// Configure the browserSync task
gulp.task('browserSync', function (done) {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: ''
        },
        port: process.env.PORT || 8080
    });
    done()
})

// Dev task with browserSync
//old:
/*
 gulp.task('dev', ['browserSync', 'sass', 'minify-css', 'minify-js', 'images'], function () {
     gulp.watch('scss/!*.scss', ['sass']);
     gulp.watch('css/!*.css', ['minify-css']);
     gulp.watch('js/!*.js', ['minify-js']);
     // Reloads the browser whenever HTML or JS files change
     gulp.watch('*.html', browserSync.reload);
     gulp.watch('js/!**!/!*.js', browserSync.reload);
 });*/

//new
gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch('app/scss/*.scss')
        .on('change', function(path, stats) {
            console.log('File ' + path + ' was changed');
        }).on('unlink', function(path) {
        console.log('File ' + path + ' was removed');
    });
});
```

watch task:

```
gulp.task('watch', function (done) {
    gulp.watch('scss/*.scss', gulp.series('sass'));
    gulp.watch('css/!*.css', gulp.series('minify-css'));
    gulp.watch('js/!*.js', gulp.series('minify-js'));
    // Reloads the browser whenever HTML or JS files change
    gulp.watch('*.html', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('js/!**/!*.js', browserSync.reload);
    return
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. it does run now but nothing works..no content is shown and I get weird errors about jquery is not defined (Im using jquery) or Unexpected token < (coming from a different library that I use). It must be connected to gulp as when I just open my index.html file (without running it with gulp), everything works fine

Comment: Your new watch task seems to only watch the scss files, could this be the cause of the issues you mentioned? @javascripting Can you provide the errors that occur?

Comment: I just edited my question and added my watch task (did it with the gulp.series like you said)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of undefined (coming from jquery waypoints), Unexpected token < (from jquery), jQuery is not defined (comes from jquery easing library), Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined (from typed library)

Comment: you had a small error in your watch task, can you use the updated watch task above? @javascripting

Comment: okay i did. when I run gulp watch I get the following error: watching scss/*.scss: watch task has to be a function (optionally generated by using gulp.parallel or gulp.series)

Comment: I updated the watch task, the second argument of watch also needs the new `gulp.series` @javascripting

Comment: thank you. so now it all seems to compile well but i only get a CANNOT get when running gulp watch

Comment: Can you further specify the error? CANNOT sounds like it cannot find the file? @javascripting

Comment: oh sorry!!! when I started rewriting things, trying to make it work again, I changed the path, just noticed it and it wasnt gulp related. It works great without any errors now. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me !!!

Comment: So actually I just run it and the watcher doesnt do anything. I have to refresh the page myself. Also sass files dont seem to be compiled to css

Comment: Does the console show that the changes were detected? What gulp task did you run? @javascripting

Comment: i run gulp watch and no changes are being detected in the console

Comment: a return statement seems necessary, could you try the new watch? @javascripting

Comment: it doesnt really change anything :/

Comment: the return doesnt really do anything. also somehow it wont even start the app (gulp watch), i added browserSync to gult default task and i can start app (when running gulp default) but no changes are being detected (only when i restart gulp))

Answer (score 0):

I tried using function instead gulp.task() and it worked for me. I found this solution in a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QgMQeLymAdU)

```
// compile scss into css
function style() {
    // 1. where is my scss file
    return gulp.src('./app/scss/**/*.scss')
    // 2. pass that file through sass compiler
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    // 3. where do I save the compiled CSS?
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/css'))
    // 4. stream changes to all browser
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
}

function watch() {
    gulp.watch('./app/scss/**/*.scss', style);
    gulp.watch('./app/**/*.html').on('change', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('./app/js/**/*.js').on('change', browserSync.reload);
}

exports.style = style;
exports.watch = watch;
```